# naming convention for gmail header references for scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Hi let me start by just saying a big thank you to all involved hear. 
Bering a little rusty in scripting theinfo in stackoverflow 
has been fantastic Thank you.

My Question 
When I look at the header of a gmail via show original
are the variables names used eg "Return-Path", "Sender", "X-Mailer" 
can they be used in a script to acess the entries in these variables
for example 
   var messages = threads[i].getX-Mailers();
   or 
   Logger.log(messages[j].getReturn-Path());

The reason for asking is looking at the examples of scripts 
for Google sheets & my lack of knowledge I was interested
if the variables names wher all acessable via a script

My apologies for any errors but have had to dust off
the programming gray cells

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to explore the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) and maybe the [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)
in particular. That should get you started...

Comment: Hi JVP thank you for your info, sorry if I came across as  a newbie, did not know that these sites existed

Comment: No problem whatsoever, Richard.